# call magento dashboard using php anchor

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How do I call the magento dashobard using an anchor? I need to call the magento dashboard when I put it in an anchor?

```
<a href="<?php //what do I add here?  ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code which is working in my one of custom extension in magento custom grid.
you can use like below.

```
<a href="<?php echo  Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/dashboard/index");?>" target="_blank">
test
</a>
```

hope this will sure work for you. let me know if i can help you further.